# Powershell run as error: unable to run - powershell

Tags: powershell

I've got a .ps1 script that I use to open a new instance of powershell as a different user:

```
runas /netonly /user:******\******* powershell
```

Until today it worked fine but now it returns the following error:

```
Attempting to start powershell as user "*******\********" ...
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - powershell
2: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Has anyone else encountered this error before, are there any known fixes?

Comment: If you want to run PowerShell as different user why not use `Start-Process powershell -Credential ***\***` ?

Answer (score 0):

OP here: Solved this, didn't realise that I had accidentally overwritten a PATH Local Environment Variable. For future poor souls like me, the fix is:

System Properties -> Advanced Tab -> Environment Variables -> System Variables:Path -> add C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0

I'm sure there is a better solution however